# jQuery UI Sortable behaving unintuitively - difficult to move up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

As you can see in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2w0Lq3to/), **you have to drag the item to the right in order to be able to move it up and down.**

**I'd like the user to be able to move the item straight up and down, or even to the left and down.** Obviously it's not intuitive to have to drag to the right just to reorder vertically.

The arrow icon is the `handle`, the part you have to click and drag to move the item.

**HTML:**

```
<body class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Testeroo</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <ul class="sortable fa-ul">
        <li>
          <i class="fa-li fas fa-arrows-alt-v fa-lg"></i>
          <input value="One" />
          <input value="Two" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fa-li fas fa-arrows-alt-v fa-lg"></i>
          <input value="One" />
          <input value="Two" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({ handle: "i.fa-li" });
```

Uses icons from [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com), that's what the `fa*` classes are. I'm also using Bootstrap, if it makes any difference, which is also in the Fiddle.

Comment: By the way, I'm sure this is intended behavior, I just don't know how to override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sortable's` [`axis`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-axis) option to enable the sortable and then you would be able to move the item straight up and down, or even to the left and down.

I have modified your demo and created a [**NEW DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/2w0Lq3to/5/).

Here is how you can add the `axis` option:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({ 
    handle: "i.fa-li",
    axis: "y"
});
```

Comment: That's definitely what I'm looking for. Is it a known problem that moving an item too quickly causes the order to not change? Or is it something on my end?

Comment: I am not sure that it is a know problem or not, but I can't see any major issues with your code as well that is causing such type of a behavior. I think you should have a deeper look at the API documentation of the jquery-ui sortable and the way to customize the layout of the handle, I am sure you would get your answer from there :)

Comment: I'm doubtful it's a result of the handle, but it's possible. Regardless, that's a new question, I was just wondering if you knew anything off the top of your head. This was the answer I was looking for, and I've marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This is a result of your handle `i.fa-li` not residing within the boundaries of the `ul`.  If you put a `background-color` on the `ul` element, you will see that the handles are outside, so your mouse doesn't enter the sortable area until you drag to the right.

You need to adjust your CSS so that the handle is inside of the `ul` area to start and it won't do this.

For demonstration, I moved the `fa-li` elements to back to the right, and padded the rest of the `li` elements to account for it with `&nbsp;`.  It's a hack, but it shows that it can be fixed:

https://jsfiddle.net/2w0Lq3to/2/

Here's a better fix using CSS and a `.pad` element:

https://jsfiddle.net/2w0Lq3to/3/

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what's going on in the CSS for the second Fiddle? I adjusted the `em` values a little to see if I could make it even more forgiving (to allow a user to move down and left), and I *think* I was successful, but it had a bad side effect: https://jsfiddle.net/1hez6qaq/

Comment: You are overflowing the width of your `li` element.  Make it wider, either a fixed width, or a percentage larger than 100%:  https://jsfiddle.net/1hez6qaq/2/